# Compare Google Maps Marker id with id in SQLite database

Tags: java, android, sqlite, google-maps

I'm trying to compare the value of Markers with an id in my pre-made SQLite database. The reason being is so that I can have specific details for specific markers.
For example:

If the marker clicked has id = 1 then I wish to search the database for id '1' and then grab the details from that row. I thought it was simple enough to just loop through the database, but this doesn't seem to be working. My current code is:

```
final Cursor dbId = monDatabase.database.rawQuery("SELECT _id from monuments", null);
    int idColumnCount = dbId.getColumnCount();
    dbId.moveToFirst();
    while(dbId.isAfterLast() == false) {
        for(int f = 0; f < idColumnCount; f++) {
            mainMarkerId = dbId.getInt(0);

            map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
                    if(marker.getId().equals("m" + mainMarkerId)){
                        Log.v("marker.getId()", "the id is: " + marker.getId());
                        selectDesc = monDatabase.database.rawQuery("SELECT description from monuments WHERE _id = " + mainMarkerId, null);
                        selectDesc.moveToFirst();
                        _description = selectDesc.getString(0);
                        Intent descriptionIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DisplayData.class);
                        descriptionIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, _description);
                        startActivity(descriptionIntent);
                        markerId.moveToNext();
                    }   
                }   
            });
            dbId.moveToNext();
        }
    }
```

I'm unsure if it is possible this way, or maybe I have to use a Hashmap or something.

Any help is much appreciated,

Thanks!

EDIT:

I forgot to mention that I have all the Markers already displayed on the maps, so it's more of a case of being able to get the description for that location and then passing it through to a new Intent.

SOLUTION:

Just thought I'd post the solution on here if anyone else needed it. I didn't need a Hashtable, all I used was:

```
selectDesc = monDatabase.database.rawQuery("SELECT description from monuments WHERE title = '" + marker.getTitle() + "'", null);
```

No need for all the for loops or anything. Very very simple!

Answer (score 0):

your best bet is to create a HashMap of the database elements using the database id as the key and the marker as the value so then you can pull from your database and have what marker you need